# How to handle CO2 being evolved during vacuum distillation?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, distillation

Setup: vacuum aspirator pump, distillation apparatus with stirring (instead of a bubbler). Partial vacuum around 5" Hg.

What would you suggest to hold the vacuum set-point?

Comment: Somewhere there is a vacuum pump, isn’t there? Actually controlling the vacuum level (as opposed to just pumping on it) depends on the set up and your equipment.

Comment: Is it possible to degas the solution before beginning the distillation?

Comment: A fine hand with the faucet to which your pump is attached to, or a vacuum controller.